# Cell Structure and Computing Homology Groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am computing homology group of space $X=S^{2}\cup T^{2}/\sim$ such that $S^{2}$ and $T^{2}$ gluing by there points on 2-sphere $s_{1}, s_{2}, s_{3}$ and three points on 2-torus $t_{1}, t_{2}, t_{3}$ where $s_{i}\sim t_{i}$. How can i found cell structure of this space and homology groups?

It looks like $S^{2}\lor S^{1}\lor S^{1}\lor S^{1}\lor S^{1}$ but I am not sure, maybe I should add one more $S^{2}$, I couldn't imagine it! I totally confused.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Mayer Vietoris sequence with $X_1 = S^2$, $X_2 = T^2$, $X_1 \cap X_2 = \{a, b, c\}$ and $X = X_1 \cup X_2$.

Comment: What about cell structure, how can I found it?

Comment: Try to find a way of realizing $S^2$ and $T^2$ with $3$ $0$-simplices each. With the torus you can start from the familiar square with sides identified, adding extra simplices on the edges.

Comment: I am really sorry I couldn't do it. Can you explain more? Thank you.

Comment: For $S^2$ you can take a triangle with $2$ $2$-simplexes; a top and a bottom one.
For the torus you could take a square with additional vertex in the middle of each edge: after identifying edges, you will be left with $3$ vertices.